# I am trying to plot some points on a Map, however they are not showing when I run my application?

Tags: android, google-maps, mapfragment

This is the Java Code that I have for plotting the points on My Map which I have included in my Home Fragment XML which is also below, The Map is showing well when I run the application, the zoom which I have also set is not working, is there something that I am missing from my code. Thanks

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

/**
 * Created by Aids on 09/08/2017.
 */

public class Map_Code_Home extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
    MapView mMapView;
    View mView;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        return mView;

    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        mMapView = (MapView) mView.findViewById(R.id.map);
        if(mMapView != null){
            mMapView.onCreate(null);
            mMapView.onResume();
            mMapView.getMapAsync(this);
        }
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

        MapsInitializer.initialize(getContext());
        mGoogleMap = googleMap;
        googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(48.689247, -74.044502)).title("Statue of Liberty"));

        CameraPosition SettingCamera = CameraPosition.builder().target(new LatLng(48.689247, -74.044502)).zoom(40).build();
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(SettingCamera));

    }
}
```

Below is my Map Fragment which I have in my HomeFragment XML Layout File.

```
<fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="275dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/textView3"/>
```

Comment: You should have in account this:  Zoom Level Ranges  0 - 19

Comment: Changed it to 14. Still does not appear

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove this annotation

`@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)`

and change moveCamera for animateCamera

`googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(SettingCamera));`